# Finding roots for an expression with non-elementary function

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

Is there an approach to solving this for $a$ in either closed-form or numerically?

```
  Solve[1/10  Sqrt[307/10]  (EllipticE[\[Pi]  FractionalPart[a/\[Pi]], -(158/307)] + 
   2  EllipticE[-(158/307)]  IntegerPart[a/\[Pi]]) == 1, a]
```

or

```
  NSolve[1/10  Sqrt[307/10]  (EllipticE[\[Pi]  FractionalPart[a/\[Pi]], -(158/307)] + 
   2  EllipticE[-(158/307)]  IntegerPart[a/\[Pi]]) == 1., a]
```

I solved the original problem using a combination of two different numerical approaches and found $$a = 1.6098987602286736$$

That $a$ can be substituted into the expression above to validate it is a solution.

**Update** Thanks to @LouisB, I used FindInstance and it found the root

```
  FindInstance[1/10   Sqrt[307/10] (EllipticE[\[Pi] FractionalPart[
    a/\[Pi]], -(158/307)] + 2   EllipticE[-(158/307)]   IntegerPart[a/\ 
    [Pi]]) == 1, a]

  N[{{a -> \[Pi]  Root[{-100 + 
     Sqrt[3070] EllipticE[\[Pi] FractionalPart[#1], -(158/307)] + 
     2 Sqrt[3070] EllipticE[-(158/307)] IntegerPart[#1] &, 
     0.512446691135740056635162473115}]}}, 30]
```

Comment: `FindInstance` can provide a numeric value.

Comment: @LouisB: Thank you, just tried that and indeed, it found the root.

Comment: Simpler: `A = 158/1000; B = 307/1000; NSolve[Sqrt[B]  EllipticE[a, -(A/B)] == 1,
  a]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: very clean, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = 1/10   Sqrt[
     307/10]   (EllipticE[π   FractionalPart[a/π], -(158/307)] + 
      2   EllipticE[-(158/307)]   IntegerPart[a/π]) == 1;
```

As LouisB indicated,

```
FindInstance[eqn, a][[1]] // N

(* {a -> 1.6099} *)
```

Or,

```
FindRoot[eqn, {a, 1}]

(* {a -> 1.6099} *)
```

Or bound the region for the solution

```
NSolve[{eqn, 0 < a < 10}, a]

(* {{a -> 1.6099}} *)

Solve[{eqn, 0 < a < 10}, a] // N

(* {{a -> 1.6099}} *)

Reduce[{eqn, 0 < a < 10}, a] // N

(* a == 1.6099 *)
```

**EDIT:** Without specifying a range, structure as a minimization:

```
NArgMin[(eqn[[1]] - eqn[[-1]])^2, a]

(* 1.6099 *)
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to automatically determine a range for $a$ before finding the value.

Comment: Not to my knowlege; however, the range does not have to be tight. For example, `Solve[{eqn, 0 < a < 300}, a]` works as well.

Comment: Also, to get an initial value for `FindRoot` or to determine a range, `Plot` the `LHS-RHS` of the equation.